# AWS Terraform DynamoDB restore scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I am going to restore a dynamodb table from backup and as AWS does not support restoring backups to the same table I will do the following:

1. Restore table A's backup to a new table B
2. Backup table B
3. Delete table A
4. Restore table B's backup as table A

I am using Terraform to manage resources. My questions are:

1. Will this break Terraform resource link/diff and make next deploy fail.
2. Will table A be ready to accept request while still being restored (step 4)?
3. Are there other best practices to restore a DynamoDB table?

Comment: You'll probably have to remove the table from the Terraform state (`terraform state rm`) and then import the new table (`terraform import`)

Comment: Can you parameterize the table name so callers don’t need to know the name in advance (they look it up) and thus it doesn’t have to match?

Answer (score 1):

As Mark B wrote, you will **certainly** need to import the restored table to the state file. And before that you need to remove the old one.

1. Restore through the console to the point in time you want and make sure to use the same KMS key, using as name "restored_table_name" ..
2. Take a backup of your state file

```
terraform state pull > backup_state_file_timestamp.json
```

3. Remove the old table from your terraform state file

```
terraform state rm aws_dynamodb_table.resource_name
```

4. Import the manually restored tabke into terraform (assuming you named it A)

```
terraform import aws_dynamodb_table.resource_name restored_table_name
```

In the tf code you will be referencing the name as shown below, hence the new table name doesnt really matter (unless you hardocded it somewhere)

```
aws_dynamodb_table.resource_name.restored_table_name
```